# How to install Pyls on MacOS?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to install python language server on my Mac. In the installation guide in *pyls*' repo there's a tip saying that if I encounter an error 
`"'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings"`, I need to upgrade *setuptools*. The problem is that i can't modify it because the directory is protected by MacOS. I've already tried downloading *pyls*' source and changing the *setup.py* file so it'll import *setuptools* from another directory but it didn't help much. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use sudo

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

or, you can create your own, personal, environment using virtual env:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

where you can install your own versions of packages that can differ from packages installed system wide.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. `sudo` won't work, because even the root user doesn't have permission to change these files. I have a question though - how can I install this module so my linter can access it from any project? I don't need to create a new environment for each of them since they're small and have quite similar dependencies.

Comment: You can play with Integrity Protection to get access to protected areas: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html

Comment: How about building it in some kind of environment and moving it to the *site-packages* folder? Is it possible?

Comment: In general, you should be able to set Python inside IDE. E.g. in PyCharm you can choose virtual env while creatnig new project.